For IDEA plugin development, in the Solution window there is a symbolic link folder. how to Reload Project?
enter image description here
I have developed a plugin using IDEA, which allows users to right-click on any folder in the Solution window, create a code file, and place it into the folder. However, if the folder is a symbolic link, after creating the file, IDEA will display the parent folder of the new file as if it were created (even though it is not physically created on the disk, just a display issue). A manual “Reload Project” is required by right-clicking on the parent project. How can I solve this problem? (I have tried many APIs already.) Thank you to all the experts for your guidance.
package coocoogame.com.et_tool;

import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction;
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnActionEvent;
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.CommonDataKeys;
import com.intellij.openapi.application.ApplicationManager;
import com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemDataKeys;
import com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ProjectSystemId;
import com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.execution.ProgressExecutionMode;
import com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil;
import com.intellij.openapi.project.Project;
import com.intellij.openapi.ui.Messages;
import com.intellij.openapi.vfs.LocalFileSystem;
import com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VfsUtil;
import com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VirtualFile;
import com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VirtualFileManager;
import com.intellij.openapi.wm.ToolWindow;
import com.intellij.openapi.wm.ToolWindowId;
import com.intellij.openapi.wm.ToolWindowManager;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class CreateCsFileAction extends AnAction {

    // 定义一个字符串模板，其中${fileName}是占位符
    private static final String TEMPLATESystem = "namespace ET${locationType} \n { \n   [FriendOf(typeof(${fileName}))] \n" +
            " [EntitySystemOf(typeof(${fileName}))] \n" +
            "public static partial class ${fileName}System  { \n" +
            "[EntitySystem] \n  private static void Awake(this ${fileName} self) \n { \n  } \n " +
            " [EntitySystem] \n   private static void Destroy(this ${fileName} self) \n { \n  } \n " +
            "} \n }";
    private static final String TEMPLATEComponent = "namespace ET${locationType} \n { " +
            "\n   //[ChildOf(typeof(${fileName}))] \n" +
            "\n   [ComponentOf(typeof(${fileName}))] \n" +

            "public  class ${fileName} : Entity, IAwake, IDestroy   { \n" +
            "\n \n" +
            "} \n }";

    private static final String TEMPLATEMessageHandler = "namespace ET${locationType} \n { " +
            "\n    [MessageHandler(SceneType.Current)] \n" +


            "public  class ${fileName} : MessageHandler<Scene, ${fileName}>   { \n" +
            " protected override async ETTask Run(Scene root, ${fileName} message) \n {"+
            "\n \n" +
            "   await ETTask.CompletedTask; \n }"+

            "} \n }";

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
        Project project = e.getData(CommonDataKeys.PROJECT);

        ProjectSystemId projectSystemId = e.getData(ExternalSystemDataKeys.EXTERNAL_SYSTEM_ID);
        if (project == null) return;

        VirtualFile[] selectedFiles = e.getData(CommonDataKeys.VIRTUAL_FILE_ARRAY);
        if (selectedFiles == null || selectedFiles.length == 0) return;

        VirtualFile selectedFile = selectedFiles[0];
        if (!selectedFile.isDirectory()) {
            selectedFile = selectedFile.getParent();
        }

        if (selectedFile == null || !selectedFile.isDirectory()) return;
        Path pathToCheck = Paths.get(selectedFile.getPath());
        if (Files.isSymbolicLink(pathToCheck)) {
            // 获取符号链接的目标路径
            try {
                Path realPath = Files.readSymbolicLink(pathToCheck);
                Messages.showMessageDialog(project, "这个是软连接!" + realPath, "Error ", Messages.getErrorIcon());
                return;
            } catch (IOException exx) {
                exx.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


        // 显示对话框并获取文件名
        FileNameInputDialog dialog = new FileNameInputDialog(project);
        dialog.show();
        if (dialog.isOK()) {
            String fileName = dialog.getFileName();
            var selectedLocationType = dialog.getSelectedLocationType();//选择的生成位置
            var selectedCSType = dialog.getSelectedCSType();//获得要生成的component还是System


            if (fileName != null && !fileName.isEmpty()) {

                var realPath=getRealPath(selectedFile.getPath());
                createFile(project,projectSystemId,realPath, fileName, selectedLocationType, selectedCSType);

                       }
        }

    }

    private void createFile(Project project,ProjectSystemId projectSystemId, String directory, String fileName, LocationType locationType, CSType csType) {
        String fullFileName = fileName + ".cs";


        // 构造文件的完整路径
        String filePath = directory + "/" + fullFileName;


        String fileContent = "";
        if (csType == CSType.System) {
            if (locationType == LocationType.Client || locationType == LocationType.Server) {
                fileContent = TEMPLATESystem.replace("${fileName}", fileName).replace("${locationType}", "." + locationType.name());
            } else {
                fileContent = TEMPLATESystem.replace("${fileName}", fileName).replace("${locationType}", "");
            }

        } else if (csType == CSType.Component) {
            if (locationType == LocationType.Client || locationType == LocationType.Server) {
                fileContent = TEMPLATEComponent.replace("${fileName}", fileName).replace("${locationType}", "." + locationType.name());
            } else {
                fileContent = TEMPLATEComponent.replace("${fileName}", fileName).replace("${locationType}", "");
            }
        } else if (csType == CSType.MessageHandler) {
            if (locationType == LocationType.Client || locationType == LocationType.Server) {
                fileContent = TEMPLATEMessageHandler.replace("${fileName}", fileName).replace("${locationType}", "." + locationType.name());
            } else {
                fileContent = TEMPLATEMessageHandler.replace("${fileName}", fileName).replace("${locationType}", "");
            }
        }
        Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
        try {
            // 如果文件不存在，则创建文件并写入内容
            if (!Files.exists(path)) {
                Files.createFile(path);
            }
            // 使用 Files.write 方法写入内容到文件
            Files.write(path, fileContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));


            // 刷新 IntelliJ 的文件系统视图以识别新文件或更改

            VirtualFile newFile = LocalFileSystem.getInstance().refreshAndFindFileByPath(filePath);
            if (newFile != null) {

                Messages.showMessageDialog(project, "File created and content written successfully: " + filePath, "Success", Messages.getInformationIcon());
                       // ApplicationManager.getApplication().restart();
               // VirtualFileManager.getInstance().syncRefresh();
                //ProjectView.getInstance(project).refresh();
                ApplicationManager.getApplication().invokeLater(() -> {
                    VirtualFileManager.getInstance().asyncRefresh(() -> {
                        ApplicationManager.getApplication().invokeLater(() -> {
                            ToolWindowManager toolWindowManager = ToolWindowManager.getInstance(project);
                            ToolWindow projectViewToolWindow = toolWindowManager.getToolWindow(ToolWindowId.PROJECT_VIEW);
                            if (projectViewToolWindow != null) {
                                projectViewToolWindow.activate(null);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
                VfsUtil.markDirtyAndRefresh(false, true, false, newFile.getParent()); // refresh parent only
                ExternalSystemUtil.refreshProject(project,projectSystemId,project.getBasePath(),false, ProgressExecutionMode.IN_BACKGROUND_ASYNC);


            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Messages.showMessageDialog(project, "Error creating file or writing content: " + ex.getMessage(), "Error", Messages.getErrorIcon());
        }
    }


    private String getRealPath(String pathString) {
        try {
            Path pathToCheck = Paths.get(pathString);
            if (Files.isSymbolicLink(pathToCheck)) {
                // 获取符号链接的目标路径
                Path realPath = Files.readSymbolicLink(pathToCheck).toAbsolutePath().normalize(); // Resolve and normalize
                return realPath.toString();
            } else {

                return pathToCheck.toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString(); // Normalize for consistency
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // ex.printStackTrace(); // Log for debugging
            //Messages.showMessageDialog(project,"Error resolving symbolic link: " + ex.getMessage(),"Error",Messages.getErrorIcon());
            return null;
        }

    }
}


